# throw checked Exceptions from mocks with Mockito

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to have one of my mocked objects throw a checked Exception when a particular method is called. I'm trying the following.

```
@Test(expectedExceptions = SomeException.class)
public void throwCheckedException() {
    List<String> list = mock(List.class);
    when(list.get(0)).thenThrow(new SomeException());
    String test = list.get(0);
}

public class SomeException extends Exception {
}
```

However, that produces the following error.

```
org.testng.TestException: 
Expected exception com.testing.MockitoCheckedExceptions$SomeException but got org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Checked exception is invalid for this method!
Invalid: com.testing.MockitoCheckedExceptions$SomeException
```

Looking at the [Mockito documentation](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.5/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html), they only use `RuntimeException`, is it not possible to throw checked Exceptions from a mock object with Mockito?

Answer (score 380, accepted):

Check the Java API for [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html).
The `get(int index)` method is declared to throw only the `IndexOutOfBoundException` which extends `RuntimeException`.
You are trying to tell Mockito to throw an exception `SomeException()` that is **not valid to be thrown by that particular method call**.

To clarify further.
The [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface does not provide for a checked Exception to be thrown from the `get(int index)` method and that is why Mockito is failing.
When you create the **mocked List**, Mockito will use the **definition of List**.class to creates its mock.

The behavior you are specifying with the `when(list.get(0)).thenThrow(new SomeException())` **doesn't match the method signature in List API**, because **`get(int index)` method does not throw `SomeException()`** so Mockito fails.

If you really want to do this, then have Mockito throw a `new RuntimeException()` or even better throw a `new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException()` since the API specifies that that is the only valid Exception to be thrown.

Comment: While my real code wasn't actually using List, your answer applies for that method call as well. I was mocking the wrong method. Thank you.

Comment: extra: Mocktio will not complain if you doThrow an a method without any throwables, but you will also get this exception

Comment: For Kotliners: Kotlin doesn't have checked exceptions, so you cannot normally declare (in the function signature) that the function throws an exception. However, you can annotate the function with `Throws` annotation to make the compiler generate the same bytecode as declaring throws in the equivalent Java code. See [here] (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-throws/index.html) for more details.

Comment: This check is enforced since the release of [Mockito 2.11.0 (see 2.10.3)](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/2.x/doc/release-notes/official.md#2110-2017-10-14-published-to-jcentermaven-central).

Comment: Does the same logic apply for Scala as well?

Comment: @Javad could you add a snippet for the suggestion you added for Kotliners

Answer (score 235):

A workaround is to use a [`willAnswer()`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.13.0/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html#thenAnswer-org.mockito.stubbing.Answer-) method.

For example the following works (and doesn't throw a `MockitoException` but actually throws a checked `Exception` as required here) using `BDDMockito`:

```
given(someObj.someMethod(stringArg1)).willAnswer( invocation -> { throw new Exception("abc msg"); });
```

The equivalent for plain Mockito would to use the `doAnswer` method

Comment: or use `willAnswer( invocation -> { throw new Exception("abc msg"); }).given(someObj).someMethod(stringArg1);` when the method returns `void`.

Comment: or use         when(someObj.someMethod(stringArg1)).thenAnswer(invocation -> {            throw new Exception("abc msg"); });

Comment: Great workaround, thanks! For Kotliners who want to (1) use that seamlessly as an extension function and (2) be able to pass several args like `willThrow()` normally allows, I've written a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/dadouf/f9ec2b5d44f20295fcadb0e8834ad45a)

Answer (score 42):

There is the solution with Kotlin :

```
given(myObject.myCall()).willAnswer {
    throw IOException("Ooops")
}
```

Where given comes from

> import org.mockito.BDDMockito.given

Comment: This will work with Java as well  `.thenAnswer((t) -> { throw new IOException(); });`

Comment: This is just working perfect. Curious to know why checked exception is a problem though

Comment: @VVB Most probably to test if the exceptions as handled well

Answer (score 28):

Note that in general, Mockito *does* allow throwing checked exceptions so long as the exception is declared in the message signature. For instance, given

```java
class BarException extends Exception {
  // this is a checked exception
}

interface Foo {
  Bar frob() throws BarException
}
```

it's legal to write:

```java
Foo foo = mock(Foo.class);
when(foo.frob()).thenThrow(BarException.class)
```

However, if you throw a checked exception not declared in the method signature, e.g.

```java
class QuxException extends Exception {
  // a different checked exception
}

Foo foo = mock(Foo.class);
when(foo.frob()).thenThrow(QuxException.class)
```

Mockito will fail at runtime with the somewhat misleading, generic message:

```html
Checked exception is invalid for this method!
Invalid: QuxException
```

This may lead you to believe that checked exceptions in general are unsupported, but in fact Mockito is only trying to tell you that **this** checked exception isn't valid **for this method**.

Comment: What if you throw a `new Exception()`?

Answer (score 7):

This works for me in Kotlin:

```
when(list.get(0)).thenThrow(new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException());
```

Note : Throw any defined exception other than Exception()

Comment: Just what I was looking for, can throw any Exception other than `Exception`

Comment: this doesn't answer the question at all ! 
`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is an unchecked exception, not a checked one.

Comment: @SaadBenbouzid yaa! I have created custom exception (Exception) and facing same problem, but not sure anyone has address this issue here :)

Answer (score 0):

For mockito, you can just use

```
when(myObject.myFunction(arg1)).thenAnswer(i -> {throw new Exception("custom test exception");});
```