# Mockito refuses to throw checked exception

Tags: java, exception, junit, mockito

I'm using Mockito for my unit tests and I encounetered a problem with throwing exception on spied object. I have done this before on this object (in different test case and it worked).
Here's the test code:

```
@Test
public void callInitiated_FsmInitializationException() throws FsmInitializationException, Exception {
    MocSbb moc = Mockito.spy(testObj);

    MocTracer tracer = Mockito.mock(MocTracer.class);
    Mockito.doReturn(tracer).when(moc).getTracer();

    CAP2InitialDPArg idp = Mockito.mock(CAP2InitialDPArg.class);
    MocFsm mocFsm = Mockito.mock(MocFsm.class);
    //Mockito.doReturn(mocFsm).when(moc).getSs7Fsm();

    TicketingLocalInterface ticketing = mockTicketingLocalInterface();
    CAP2InitialDPArgWrap idpWrap = Mockito.mock(CAP2InitialDPArgWrap.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(CAP2InitialDPArgWrap.class).withArguments(idp, tracer).thenReturn(idpWrap);

    MocSession mocSession = Mockito.mock(MocSession.class);
    Mockito.doReturn(mocSession).when(moc).getMocSession();

    Mockito.when(moc.getSs7Fsm()).thenThrow(new FsmInitializationException()); ////HERE'S THE PROBLEM

    moc.callInitiated(idp);

    verify(moc).getFailedFsm();
}
```

here's the method on which the exception should be thrown:

```
protected MocFsm getSs7Fsm() throws FsmInitializationException {
    mocFsm.setContextProvider(getMocLocalObject());
    return mocFsm;
}
```

the error I get during test execution looks like this:

```
Testcase: callInitiated_FsmInitializationException(com.nsn.as.ccs.moc.sbb.MocSbbTest):  Caused an ERROR

Checked exception is invalid for this method!
Invalid: com.nsn.as.ccs.moc.fsm.FsmInitializationException
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Checked exception is invalid for this method!
Invalid: com.nsn.as.ccs.moc.fsm.FsmInitializationException
at com.nsn.as.ccs.moc.sbb.MocSbbTest.callInitiated_FsmInitializationException(MocSbbTest.java:1194)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:322)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:309)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:112)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:73)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:297)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:222)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:161)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:135)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:133)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:112)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
```

Does anyone have any idea why it doesn't work in this case?

Comment: Not a duplicate but another question on that topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762047/throw-checked-exceptions-from-mocks-with-mockito

Comment: I have seen that, but it doesn't answer my question. thanks though

Comment: What is the type of testObj? Is it `MocSbb` or is it a super class or interface? Does the interface/parent class declare the exception also?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have finally found the solution for this problem.

We have used an anonymous class extending original `Sbb` class which was tested and in this extended class implementation of mentioned method was altered and `throws` expression was removed which caused the problem.

I should have read my colleagues code more carefully.

Comment: It happened to my also, but with a class implementing an interface

Answer (score 5):

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55351849/2968988). Using Mockito's `doAnswer` instead of `thenThrow` method solved my issue.

```
Mockito.doAnswer(
      invocation -> {
        throw new Exception("Something went wrong");
      })
  .when(moc)
  .getSs7Fsm();
```

I know it's too late but just in case anyone faces the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

I have a feeling the solution is to use doThrow() syntax instead of when().thenThrow(). When spying it is safer to use doThrow/doReturn syntax for stubbing. The reasons are somewhat described in the documentation: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13

I think we can improve an exception message in this instance so that it is m

Comment: Reason: Stubbing voids requires different approach from Mockito.when(Object) because the compiler does not like void methods inside brackets...

Comment: This did not work for me.  What ended up working was actually changing the exception to a RuntimeException type.  It's not clear to me why Mockito doesn't allow checked exceptions to be thrown with these methods.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is very old but my solution it could be of help to someone:
I solved this same error by changing the visibility of my method to be test to public.

In this case you whould have change

```
protected MocFsm getSs7Fsm() throws FsmInitializationException {
    ...
}
```

to

```
public MocFsm getSs7Fsm() throws FsmInitializationException {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, since I was using @SneakyThrows on my void method, I had to throw a RuntimeException, instead of a normal exception, in my mock, so

```
doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).doStuff(any());
```