# How to mock an exception when creating an instance of a new class using Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

Within a method, I have an exception being caught which I want to mock.

I know how to mock an object to throw an exception using mock.doSomething(), but I need to throw a remote exception when a class makes a new instance of itself.

```
transient Bicycle bike = null;

public Bicycle getBicycle() {
    if (bike == null) {
        try {
            bike = new Bicycle(this);
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
            System.out.println("No bikes found");
        }
    }
    return bike;
}
```

I want to be able to mock everything in the try block, but I don't understand how you mock the creation of a new class, the following line to be specific:

```
bike = new Bicycle(this);
```

I have tried many different Mockito tests, such as:

```
Bicycle b = mock(Bicycle.class);
Mockito.doThrow(new RemoteException()).when(b = new Bicycle());
```

Although I understand this will and is not working, I want to do something similar.

I have read the Mockito docs and haven't found anything useful:

http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force Mockito to throw RemoteException in JUnit test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15582395/how-to-force-mockito-to-throw-remoteexception-in-junit-test)

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström This is definitely not a duplicate. I wrote the previous question and I am looking for two different answers from both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Mockito extension, PowerMock, in cases like this. It allows constructors to be mocked (see https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor).

In this case, you would write something like the following test:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ClassUnderTest.class, Bicycle.class})
public class ConstructorMockingTest
{
    @Test
    public void getBicycle()
    {
        ClassUnderTest tested = new ClassUnderTest();
        whenNew(Bicycle.class).withArguments(tested).thenThrow(new RemoteException());

        Bicycle bicycle = tested.getBicycle();

        assertNull(bicycle);
    }
}
```

More examples can be found at: https://code.google.com/p/powermock/source/browse/trunk/modules/module-test/mockito/junit4/src/test/java/samples/powermockito/junit4/whennew/WhenNewTest.java

Answer (score 7):

You don't generally mock constructors. You *can* do with tools like [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/), but I'd generally suggest you don't.

Currently, your code isn't actually testable, if you want to control what happens when a new `Bicycle` is constructed. Is constructing a `Bicycle` actually a complex operation? Perhaps you want a `BicycleFactory`, which can be passed into your class as a dependency, for example - *then* you could mock `BicycleFactory.createBicycle` or whatever you call it.

Constructors are like static methods - when you use them, you're tightly bound to the specific code you're calling; there's no clean way to inject other behaviour without approaches like PowerMock's.

Comment: I don't think I have made it clear but Bicycle is an instance of another class, not the one this method is currently in. The method retrieves the instance, but if it is null I want to create a new one. I'm not sure if that would change anything or not?

Comment: @JohnVasiliou: No, not at all. You're still calling a constructor - which is fundamentally not something you can simply mock out in tests.

Comment: There are plenty of real-world situations where instantiating a dependency directly is the right thing to do. For one such example, consider a business service class which needs to send a notification via e-mail; in Java, a well known API for email is [Apache Commons Email](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email), where you normally instantiate an `Email` subclass (usually, `SimpleEmail`), call a few setters/adders, and finally call the `send()` method. It's simple, object-oriented, *and* easy to unit test.

Comment: @Rogério: How would you unit test that then? I'd expect to have two classes in that example: one which represents the email itself (which wouldn't be faked out) and one which represents an email *service* capable of sending an email - and that would be faked out.

Comment: @JonSkeet You can write a unit test for the business service class in the way shown in my answer to this question, using PowerMock. A shorter, simpler test can also be written with the JMockit API (which I develop); if you want, I can show the code here. Note that the email API you described is similar to what's in the [Spring framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mail.html), with a value-object class `SimpleMailMessage` and a stateless `MailSender` service interface. Personally, I prefer the Apache API, which is simpler and more object-oriented.

Comment: @Rogério: I wouldn't say that any approach which *requires* PowerMock or something similar counts as "easy to unit test". I completely disagree with your idea of "more object-oriented" - an email is logically separate from "a service capable of sending an email", in my view. I think we'll have to agree to differ on this one.

Comment: @JonSkeet PowerMock and JMockit are mocking tools with their own strengths and weaknesses, like anything else. In general, creation of unit tests with JMockit is demonstrably easier (when used in its area of applicability) than with any other mocking API (I can - and have - write any amount of explanations and examples for this, but you probably agree this is not the place and time for it). About object-oriented code, I disagree that any approach which favors "objects" with no behavior and "objects" with no state is a good one. I prefer true objects, with state *and* behavior.

Comment: @Rogério: I prefer objects with the *appropriate* amount of state and behaviour to the scenario. An `Email` class may have *some* behaviour - but I wouldn't expect it to actually perform any network operations. As I said, however, I think we'll have to agree to differ. As to the merits of JMockit vs other frameworks - I'd expect the others of other frameworks to put forth similar arguments in favour of their own creations. You're not exactly impartial ;)

Comment: @JonSkeet And yes, I think we'll have to agree to disagree on this, but I would like to point out two things: 1) there is no support for your preference of "anemic objects" over true objects in the programming literature (if you think there is, please provide the reference); 2) from personal experience, such non-OO code is, sadly, not hard to find in the real world (I've seen it in both Java and C#.NET projects), and easily shown to be worse than the OO alternative.

Comment: @Rogério: So you'd like to agree to differ, so long as you actually keep arguing? I'm *not* going to reply to those points, as otherwise it would just perpetuate the discussion, which is inappropriate here.

Comment: @JonSkeet The Apache `Email` class has only *one* very simple and intuitive "behaviour" method: `Email#send()`. I don't see how one can justify moving it to a separate type, for no clear reason. Regarding JMockit vs other frameworks, trust me, I would *love* to discuss it with the other mocking tool developers. Those familiar with the JMockit project site know that it provides *a lot* more objective information, and a *huge* amount of example tests; in fact, I have gone out of my way to provide data for evaluation purposes; and the only one to do so, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getBicycle()` now does at least two things. It retrieves ("gets") a `Bicycle`, and it creates a `Bicycle`. Ideally a method or class should do only one thing, and do it well.

Put the creation of the object in a separate method `createBicycle()` or separate `BicycleFactory` and mock that.