# How can I mock a call to a function using mockito in a java junit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a jUnit test which tests one of my functions. In that function I make a call to another class's method which I want to mock using mockito. However, I can't seem to actually mock this. Here is what my jUnit test looks like:

```
@Test
public void testingSomething() throws Exception {

    mock(AuthHelper.class);
    when(new AuthHelper().authenticateUser(null)).thenReturn(true);

    Boolean response = new MainClassImTesting().test();
    assertTrue(response);
}
```

EDIT: In my MainClassImTesting().test() function that I'm calling, it makes a call to authenticateUser() and passes it a hashMap.

Comment: Did you pass null because you did not knpw how to construct a `Matcher` or because you want the object to mock what happens when a null value is passed ?

Comment: [Mockito can't be used to _mock all new instances of a type_.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647418/how-to-mock-an-exception-when-creating-an-instance-of-a-new-class-using-mockito) Mockito.mock will return an AuthHelper instance for you to pass into `when` and `MainClassImTesting.test`, or you'll need to use PowerMock to mock the constructor call itself.

Comment: @Dici I just passed a null value because I didn't think it was even important. Wouldn't the mock work in a way that when that function is called, it returns whatever I want it to regardless of what I'm passing in?

Comment: @JeffBowman based on what you're saying, I wouldn't be able to test my scenario using Mockito.mock. However, if I was to pass in an instance of an AuthHelper to myMainClassImTesting() then Mockito would be suitable?

Comment: @DanielD Correct. You can make AuthHelper a constructor parameter, or a method parameter. You can even have `yourMethod()` delegate to `yourMethod(AuthHelper)` and only test the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mockito will allow you create a mock object and have its methods return expected results. So in this case, if you want the authenticateUser method of your mocked AuthHelper instance return true regardless of the value of the HashMap parameter, your code would look something like this:

```
AuthHelper mockAuthHelper = mock(AuthHelper.class);
when(mockAuthHelper.authenticateUser(any(HashMap.class))).thenReturn(true);
```

However, your mocked object is useless to your MainClassImTesting unless it has access or reference to it. You can achieve that by adding AuthHelper to the constructor of MainClassImTesting so that the class (including your test method) has access to it.

```
MainClassImTesting unitUnderTest = new MainClassImTesting(mockAuthHelper);
Boolean response = unitUnderTest.test();
assertTrue(response);
```

Or if your test method is the only method that needs AuthHelper, you can simply make AuthHelper a method parameter.

```
MainClassImTesting unitUnderTest = new MainClassImTesting();
Boolean response = unitUnderTest.test(mockAuthHelper);
assertTrue(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mock the function call for any parameter of type A, just do :

```
AuthHelper authHelper = Mockito.mock(AuthHelper.class);
Mockito.when(authHelper.authenticateUser(any(A.class))).thenReturn(true);
```

Comment: I got a compile error when I did this:  when(new AuthHelper().authenticateUser(any(a.class))).thenReturn(true);. My function is expecting a hashMap, not A.class

Comment: Of course, you have to use the right type. I did not know the signature of your method so I used `A` as an example

Comment: I see what you mean. Sorry, I thought using any() could work with anything.

Comment: Nope, it is much more powerful, you can specify matchers for the type of parameter, for example to observe the right behaviour for some pattern of parameter