# With Mockito, how to stub a method with return type void which throws an exception when a certain argument is passed?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Here is the principal **Mockito** documentation for [stubbing void methods with exceptions](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#5). However, the example in the Mockito doc stubs a **parameterless** method. **What if the method has parameters** and the method throws an *Exception* if the a parameter does not fulfills the contract?

So for the following class...

```
public class UserAccountManager {    
   /**
    * @throws Exception if user with provided username already exists
    */
    public void createAccount(User user) throws Exception {
        // db access code ...
    }
}
```

... how can **UserAccountManager.createAccount be mocked** with **Mockito** so that it **throws an Exception** if a **certain User object is passed** as an argument to the method?

Comment: What about this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762047/throw-checked-exceptions-from-mocks-with-mockito ?

Comment: @gontard come on, the q/a you linked to is not even remotely answering the topic of this question!

Comment: right, may be there wasn't this question before because it is completely obvious.

Comment: @gontard you mean that the question is so obvious that it's not worth to be asked/answered here on SO?

Comment: IMHO The [mockito documentation](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#5) is very clear.

Comment: @gontard the whole point of the question is: how to mock a void method throwing an exception **if and only if a certain argument** is passed to the method. IN THE EXAMPLE GIVEN: an Exception is thrown if the passed **User object alread EXISTS**!

Comment: Before reading the section 5 (Stubbing void methods with exceptions) you should read the section 3 (Argument matchers)

Comment: Kandilaki, if you feel the documentation for Mockito is inadequate, then a better course of action might be to contact the Mockito team, so they can improve it.  Did you think of posting in the Mockito google group?  (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/mockito)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Mockito doc](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#5) already shows an example of how to stub a *parameterless* void method with exceptions.

However, for **stubbing a void method with parameters and exceptions**, do this:

Since the **return type of createAccount is void**, you have to use [doThrow](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12):

```
User existingUser = ... // Construct a user which is supposed to exist
UserAccountManager accountMng = mock(UserAccountManager.class);    

doThrow(new Exception()).when(accountMng).createAccount(eq(existingUser));
```

Note the usage of the [eq](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/Matchers.html#eq%28T%29) Matcher. If the argument's type (in this case User) does not implement *equals* on its own you can also try to use the [refEq](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/Matchers.html#refEq%28T%29) Matcher.

Comment: Can you please give me some hints for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27142314/powermock-mocking-void-method-throws-error