# NullPointerException in mockito unit test

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, mockito

Here is my `SendEmail` class that I am trying to unit test. I am getting a NullPointerException on the line shown below, but I don't know why.

Also, am I organizing the code properly? I don't exactly know if I am using mockito correctly.

```
public class StatsTest extends AbstractTestCase {
    @Mock
    MultiPartEmail MultiPartEmailMock;
    StatsTest statsTestObj;
    SendEmail mockedEmail;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Throwable {
        super.setUp();
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test(expected = ValidationException.class)
    public void testSendEmail() throws EmailException, IOException {
        MultiPartEmail multiPartEmailMock;
        SendEmail mockedEmail = Mockito.mock(SendEmail.class);
        Mockito.when((mockedEmail.getHtmlEmail()).send()) 
            .thenThrow(new ValidationException("Could not send the Email."));

        ^^ the line above is where the null pointer error is

        mockedEmail.sendEmail();
    }
}
```

Here is the class under test:

```
public class SendEmail {
    private StringBuilder emailBody;
    private String senderEmail;
    private ArrayList<String> receiversEmails;
    private String emailSubject;
    private String hostName;
    private MultiPartEmail htmlEmail;

    public SendEmail(StringBuilder emailBody, String senderEmail, ArrayList<String> 
        receiversEmails, String emailSubject, String hostName, MultiPartEmail htmlEmail) {
        this.setEmailBody(emailBody);
        this.setSenderEmail(senderEmail);
        this.setReceiversEmails(receiversEmails);
        this.setEmailSubject(emailSubject);
        this.setHostName(hostName);
        this.setHtmlEmail(htmlEmail);
    }

    public void sendEmail()throws IOException, EmailException{

        htmlEmail.setHostName(getHostName());
        htmlEmail.addTo(getReceiversEmails().get(0));
        for(int i=0; i<getReceiversEmails().size(); i++){
            htmlEmail.addCc(getReceiversEmails().get(i));   
        }
        htmlEmail.setFrom(getSenderEmail());
        htmlEmail.setSubject(getEmailSubject());
        htmlEmail.setMsg((getEmailBody()).toString());
        htmlEmail.send();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give me a line number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are a bit confused on what you need to be testing and mocking. Mockito offers different ways to create mock object, for example: `@Mock` or `Mockito.mock()`. There are also different ways to *inject* those mock objects into the *class under test* in order to unit test methods on that class.

Without all the details of the exception or other classes, this will not be a complete answer, but I hope it helps clear up some of the concepts.

*Note: the following might not compile, but hopefully you'll get the idea.*

```
public class StatsTest extends AbstractTestCase {
    @Mock MultiPartEmail mockMultiPartEmail; // this mock will be used in the instantiaion of the class under test
    SendEmail sendEmail; // renamed as this is not a mock, it is the class under test

    // define some things we can make assertions against (probably in some other tests...)
    private static final StringBuilder BODY = new StringBuilder("body");
    private static final String SENDER = "sender@foo.com";
    private static final Collection<String> RECIPIENTS = Arrays.asList("recepient@foo.com")
    private static final String SUBJECT = "subject";
    private static final String HOSTNAME = "hostname";

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Throwable {
        super.setUp();
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); // will instantiate "mockMultiPartEmail"

        // instantiate our class under test
        sendEmail = new SendEmail(BODY, SENDER, RECIPIENTS, SUBJECT, HOSTNAME, mockMultiPartEmail);
    }

    @Test(expected = ValidationException.class)
    public void testSendEmail() throws EmailException, IOException {
        // given some condition
        Mockito.when(mockMultiPartEmail.send()).thenThrow(new ValidationException("Could not send the Email."));

        // when the method under test is called
        sendEmail.sendEmail();

        // then the exception will be thrown (and you have correctly expected this on the @Test annotation)
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran it, it stops on line:

    Mockito.when(mockMultiPartEmail.send.()).thenThrow(new    
    ValidationException("Could not send the Email"));

The exception is:

    java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected <javax.xml.bind.ValidationException>butwas<org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException

caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
Checked exception is invalid for the method!
Invalid: java.xml.bind.ValidationException: Could not send the Email.

Comment: I cannot help much more without seeing all of your code! My _example_ above was coded without any real knowledge of your full codebase. The error is saying that "mockito was expecting a `ValidationException` exception, but actually got something else. From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762047/throw-checked-exceptions-from-mocks-with-mockito this looks to be caused by your test throwing something that is "not valid to be thrown by that particular method call". Does your code actually throw a `ValidationException`? From the code you have in the question, the answer is **no**