# How can I throw an SQLServerException (or SQLException) with Mockito?

Tags: kotlin, junit, mockito, mssql-jdbc, mockito-kotlin

I am unable to create an instance of SQLServerException because the ctors are all internal.  Getting below error when using SQLException

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:  Checked exception is
> invalid for this method!

Method signature (on **SQLServerPreparedStatement**):
`public boolean execute() throws SQLServerException, SQLTimeoutException`

and... `public final class SQLServerException extends SQLException`

Mock:

```
val fakeCmd : SQLServerPreparedStatement = mock()
...
whenever(fakeCmd.execute()).thenThrow(SQLException()) // this line fails
```

What am I doing wrong?  Shouldn't I be able to throw the base/super exception?

**Re Suggested Question:**
The suggested question is very different from what I'm asking, the op in the other question is trying to throw `SomeException` which is not thrown by `List.get` nor in the inheritance tree

If you see "Method signature (on SQLServerPreparedStatement)" above, the method throws `SQLServerException` => `public final class SQLServerException extends SQLException`

But it doesn't like `whenever(fakeCmd.execute()).thenThrow(SQLException())`

Further, the accepted answer as pointed out is to throw `RuntimeException` because `IndexOutOfBoundsException extends RuntimeException`

In this case, so is `SQLServerException extends SQLException`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [throw checked Exceptions from mocks with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762047/throw-checked-exceptions-from-mocks-with-mockito)

Comment: No, that question is not the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented about another question and there is a answer (not the accepted one) in the end that may be suitable in your case.

---

A workaround is to use a `willAnswer()` method.

For example the following works (and doesn't throw a MockitoException but actually throws a checked Exception as required here) using `BDDMockito`:

```kotlin
given(someObj.someMethod(stringArg1)).willAnswer(invocation -> { 
    throw new Exception("abc msg");
});
```

The equivalent for plain Mockito would to use the doAnswer method

---

Here is the direct link to that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48261005/13210306