# org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException - cannot test exception when method calls other protected methods

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit5, spring-jms

I cannot mock the private methods using mockito, but the method access specifier can be package or protected so i did that. but even after that i cannot achieve unit testing an exception throwing when the actual method contains several other protected method calls.

**source:**

```
public class ConsumeService {
    
      private DataProcessService dataProcessService;
    
    @JmsListener
      public void getMessage(final Message message) throws InterruptedException {
    
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
          TextMessage textMessage = getTextMessage(message);
          try {
            
            Map<String, String> attributes = prepareInfo(textMessage);
            dataProcessService.processRequestData(
                message.getText(), attributes);
            
    
          } catch (JMSException e) {
            log.error("JMSException in message");
          } catch (ResourceAccessException e) {
            log.error("IOException in message");
          }
        } else {
          log.error("message convertion failed!");
        }
      }
     }
     
     TextMessage getTextMessage(final Message message) {
        return (TextMessage) message;
    }
    
    Map<String, String> prepareInfo(TextMessage message) throws JMSException {

    ..
    ..
    
    return result;
  }
```

**Test method:**

```
    @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ConsumeServiceTest {

  
     
    @InjectMocks ConsumeService consumeService;
    
    @Mock DataProcessService dataProcessService;
    
    @Test
  public void receiveMessageException() throws ResourceAccessException, JMSException{
    
    TextMessage message = mock(TextMessage.class);
    TextMessage textMessage = mock(TextMessage.class);
    Map<String, String> mockMap = mock(HashMap.class);
    
    when(consumeService.getTextMessage(message)).thenReturn(textMessage); //67 line
    when(consumeService.prepareInfo(textMessage)).thenReturn(mockMap);
    
    Mockito.lenient().
    when(
        dataProcessService.processRequestData(
                textMessage.getText(), mockMap))
    .thenThrow(ResourceAccessException.class);
    
    assertThrows(
            ResourceAccessException.class,
            () -> this.consumeService.getMessage(message));
    }   
            
}
```

**Error:**

```
    org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
    when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
    For example:
        when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
    
    Also, this error might show up because:
    1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
       Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
       Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
    2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
at com.sample.rest.listner.service.ConsumeServiceTest.receiveMessageException(ConsumeServiceTest.java:67)
```

I absolutely have no clue how to resolve this. I am understanding the error is in stubing but i am not understanding how to fix this.
Secondly, an util method specifically useful for a class can be declared as private and in the same file. I do not see why mockito discourage private/static method mocking or testing in that way? Is it possible at all? i am using mockito with junit5

---

**Update**

Modified the test method

**Updated test method:**

```
@Test
  public void receiveMessageException() throws ResourceAccessException, JMSException{

    
    TextMessage message = mock(TextMessage.class);
    
    Mockito.lenient().
    when(
        dataProcessService.processRequestData(
                Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(Map.class)))
    .thenThrow(ResourceAccessException.class);
    
    assertThrows(
            ResourceAccessException.class,
            () -> this.consumeService.getMessage(message));
  }
```

and now the **error** is

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.
```

My assumption is it is failing in this line Map<String, String> attributes = prepareInfo(textMessage);
I am not sure. when i run the test in debug mode, i see attributes is an empty object.
How to throw this ResourceAccessException

Comment: Your test method snippet seems to be invalid, no method is declared. Could you please fix it? Also, could you specify which line number / `when` statement throws the `MissingMethodInvocationException`?

Comment: In the `source` snippet there is no `prepareMetaData` method, which appears in the `test method` snippet.

Comment: sorry, i have now added the test method block, and renamed the method name @StefanoCordio

Answer (score 0):

Although it was not specified in the original post, I assume that the `MissingMethodInvocationException` is thrown by:

```
when(consumeService.getTextMessage(textMessage)).thenReturn(textMessage);
```

This happens because `consumeService` is not a mock but the object under test. If you want to stub methods of the `ConsumeServiceTest` class, you need to [spy its instance](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Spy.html).

Remarks:

- [It is discouraged to use `@Spy` and `@InjectMocks` on the same field](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38573651/9714611). When this happens, it might be an indication that the class is violating the Single Responsibility Principle and you should break down that class into multiple independent classes.
- `@InjectMocks` can be avoided if constructor or setter injection is used.
- The stubbing of `consumeService.getTextMessage(textMessage)` seems unnecessary, a `TextMessage` instance is alredy the input of `consumeService.getMessage`

Comment: i understood your point. I am very new to junit5 and learning. However i have modified the test method, and the way i am mocking it now, it should throw resourceaccessexception but still it is failing.

Comment: You catch the ResourceAccessException and ignore it.

Comment: Sorry but i didn't get you.. you mean to say as i am catching it in exceptiin block that is why it is saying nothing is thrown?

Comment: The line `catch (ResourceAccessException e) {
            log.error("IOException in message");
          }` is swallowing the exception, that's why the test assertion fails, nothing is thrown outside.